# Can I use a Steam Gift Card and not give Steam credit card information?

Tags: steam

Can I use a Steam gift card to buy games instead of giving Steam my credit card info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, all you have to do is click in the top right where it shows your username, then go to **account details**.

[image]

After, go to **Add funds to your Steam wallet**.

[image]

Then on the right, **Redeem a Steam Wallet Code**.

[image]

All you have to do now is enter your code and you should be fine.

Comment: So its like putting a Psn code on a Play Station

Comment: @SuperiorAsian I can't say I've used the psn, so I wouldn't know

Comment: But I still don't need a credit card right?

Comment: @SuperiorAsian yes, you still don't need a credit card

Comment: but what about the mailing adress

Comment: @SuperiorAsian that's just for tax. To learn more, you should contact Steam directly. If this helped, don't forget to pick my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the votes